# How to search the first and last occurrence from the sample list

Tags: perl, awk, text-processing

I have a log from my application like below as an example:

```
{Fri Mar 16 19:07:47 Program: job-a: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 19:07:47 Program: job-a: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 19:07:48 Program: job-b: <blah><blah>
Fri Mar 16 19:07:48 Program: job-b: <blah><blah>
Fri Mar 16 19:07:50 Program: job-b: <blah><blah>
Fri Mar 16 19:07:51 Program: job-b: <blah><blah>
Fri Mar 16 19:07:52 Program: job-a: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 19:07:52 Program: job-a: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 19:07:53 Program: job-a: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 19:07:54 Program: job-a: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 19:07:55 Program: job-a: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 19:08:00 Program: job-a: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 19:08:01 Program: job-a: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 20:33:52 Program: job-c: <blah><blah> 
Fri Mar 16 20:45:56 Program: job-c: <blah><blah>}
```

For each Job name (`job-a`, `job-b`, `job-c`) in this case, I need to find the first and last occurrences of the line to identify the start and end times.

i.e. I need to output the program/job name, start_time and end_time as shown in my sample output below. I have shown the expected output as comma separated, but I don't really care about the delimiter as I'm only interested in the values. Ignore the curly braces at the beginning and end in the sample input/output.

```
job-a, Fri Mar 16 19:07:47, Fri Mar 16 19:08:01
job-b, Fri Mar 16 19:07:48, Fri Mar 16 19:07:51
job-c, Fri Mar 16 20:33:52, Fri Mar 16 20:45:56
```

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with `awk` and here I'm just showing how you can get first and last occurrences of each job.

```
awk '!first[$6]{ first[$6]=$4 } { last[$6]=$4 } 
    END{ for (x in last) print x, first[x], last[x] }' OFS=', ' infile
job-a:, 19:07:47, 19:08:01
job-b:, 19:07:48, 19:07:51
job-c:, 20:33:52, 20:45:56
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example in Perl:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'log.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my %jobs;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    next if $line !~ /job/;
    my ($date, $job ) = $line =~ /^(.*?)\s*Program:\s*(job.*?):/;
    if (exists $jobs{$job}) {
        $jobs{$job}->{end} = $date;
    }
    else {
        $jobs{$job}->{start} = $date;
    }
}
close $fh;

for my $job (sort keys %jobs) {
    say join ", ", $job, $jobs{$job}->{start}, $jobs{$job}->{end};
}
```